# Why is latency smaller when running website from localhost?

Tags: networking, ping, latency

When i “ping” a hostname from my remote website the latency is larger than when I ping the same hostname from localhost (or using the ping command). I use the same machine for both tests. Why is this happening?

Comment: your localhost is likely closer to your screen.

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean..can you explain please?

Comment: no, i guess it's me that didn't understand the question. the title made me think "is this guy special or something"? looks like i'm the special one, good question...

Comment: @dandavis You got it right. What isn't clear is what kind of an answer would satisfy the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the network is zero length instead of possibly 12,500 miles, or much more in the case of satellite links, and consists of zero routers instead of possibly dozens.